# How does windowing system work on MacOS?

Tags: macos

I'm really interested in computer graphics and I would like to know how windowing and graphics systems work on MacOS.
I've started to learn how to create a window in objective-c but then I told myself that it doesn't explain what does objective-c "ask" to the hardware exactly. So I've read about X11 but I still had to install another program 'XQuartz'.

Do you have any suggestions to learn how to create a window from scratch without using any framework or library on MacOS, if it is even possible? And if it's not possible on MacOS, do you know what makes it impossible (or complicated) on MacOS?

Comment: Macos does not use x11.  It has its own system  called cocoa. There are lower level apis as well but yoy must use apple frameworks to interact with graphics. Even x11 as a framework

Comment: The best place to start learning "how to create a window from scratch" would be the official [AppKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit).  Doing so without a framework or library, would be impossible as you would need that framework to interface your application with the OS that interfaces with the hardware.  Asking what objective-c "asks" the hardware is too much of a jump of oversimplification - there are many layers you're skipping over to get from one point to the other.

Comment: Understanding in intricate details of how all of this works is highly commendable, however, if you are just starting out in programming, I suggest not bogging yourself down in the weeds so early. Learn to develop your apps using the libraries and frameworks. As your skills develop, you will be able to better understand how those libraries "ask the hardware" to do what they do because you'll have a foundation of what the expected results and behavior is.

Answer (score 1):

Macs have their own windowing system called AppKit which is not based on X11. You can certainly install X11 and use it but it's not how most Mac apps work. Creating a window from the ground up with no frameworks is going to take some work, and is maybe better suited for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Even there though, this is such a rare need that you might have trouble getting an answer.

If you want to get into the real low-level details of making things work, resources exist, though you can no doubt Google as well as me. One good starting point might be the [New OSX Book](http://newosxbook.com/index.php) site.

A simple example with minimal framework code might look like this:

```
import Foundation
import AppKit

let aWindow = NSWindow(
    contentRect: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 400, 210), 
    styleMask: [.titled, .closable], 
    backing: .buffered, 
    defer: false)
aWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)

RunLoop.current.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

**What does objective-c "ask" to the hardware exactly?**

Developers use the MacOS APIs to instruct the OS to perform common tasks, like creating a window, moving a window, resizing a window. This frees developers from having to code at the hardware level, or rewriting code for writing windows all the time. What happens 'underneath' is largely transparent.

Apple has released some parts of the OS as [Open Source](https://opensource.apple.com), but I don't think Core Graphics is one of them.

Programming is a series of abstractions. Ultimately, the computer has to plot colours for each pixel of the display. So imagine an array that describes the colour value for each pixel of the display. Now imagine a way of grouping cells in that array as rectangles, circles, lines, and other shapes. And then stick NSWindow at the very top.

X11 was created as a common 'front-end' to a variety of different hardware running Unix. As with MacOS APIs, it doesn't really tell much about what goes on 'underneath'. If you want to search for video driver frameworks or low-level hardware programming, then there will be resources you can find.